# "Jetzt, wo..." - wie entstanden?

Tags: adverb, conjunction

*Wo* und *Wann* sind als Lokal- bzw. Temporaladverbien stimmig, wenn es sich um Fragesätze handelt ("*Wo kommst du her?*", "*Wann kommst du?*").

In manchen Deklarativsätzen hingegen passieren seltsame Dinge. Während

> "An dem Ort *wo* ich wohne"

(ugs. für "An dem Ort *an dem* ich...") und

> "Gestern, *als* ich ins Bett gegangen bin"

oder

> "Morgen, *wenn* du aufstehst"

Ort und Zeit sauber handhaben, steht *Jetzt* plötzlich mit *wo*:

> Jetzt, wo ich in Bielefeld lebe...

Und das lässt sich noch nicht einmal anders ausdrücken (oder doch? Allenfalls mittels "*Jetzt, da ich...*").

Kann jemand etwas etymologisches Licht auf das Wort *Wo* werfen? Oder sonstwie die Angelegenheit erhellen (vielleicht bilden Raum und Zeit ja in der deutschen Sprache eine relativistische Einheit)?

Comment: Wieso denn "allenfalls" bei "Jetzt, da ich"? "Dort, wo ich lebe, in Berlin, gibt es keinen erstklassigen Fußball mehr." Oft gehen ja Ort & Zeit Hand in Hand - letzte Saison gab es noch nominelle Erstklassigkeit. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob es wirklich so erklärt werden kann. Oft wird das "wo" ja gar nicht mit einem räumlichen Bezug versehen: "Jetzt, wo ich Professor geworden bin ..." etwa.

Comment: Ich glaube das "wo" in diesem Satz ist eine Mundart, aber kein korrektes Deutsch. Das gibt es ja regional noch schlimmer. "Der Mann, wo ich gestern gesehen habe." Alles schon gehört. "Jetzt, da ich in Bielefeld lebe ..." ist, wie ich glaube, das bessere Deutsch.

Comment: Vielleicht ist "Jetzt, wo" kein korrektes Deutsch, aber lässt es sich anders ausdrücken? Lässt sich "wo" ersetzen?

Comment: Olaf Die Antwort hast du dir selbst schon gegeben und auch @Korinna hat das Beispiel gezeigt. Ich glaube in jeder Konstruktion sollte das "wo" ersetztbar sein.

Comment: Der Duden zeigt auch ein schönes Beispiel, wo du es mit "zumal" ersetzen kannst: "warum hast du das gesagt, wo du doch weißt, wie empfindlich er ist"

Comment: @Em1: Wie würdest Du denn das "Wo" in "Jetzt wo" ersetzen?

Comment: @Olaf Bezogen auf das Bielefeld-Beispiel? Genau so, wie du und Korinna es vorschlagen. Um einfach noch andere Ideen aufzuzeigen: "Jetzt, wo ich mich in Bielefeld eingelebt habe... -> Jetzt, nachdem ich mich in Bielefeld eingelebt habe (semantisch nicht ganz sauber, aber ugs. OK)" - "Jetzt, wo ich mich endlich eingelebt hatte -> Jetzt, als ich mich endlich eingelebt hatte" - "Jetzt, wo du endlich hier bist -> Jetzt, da du endlich hier bist" ...

Comment: @Em1: Ich weiß nicht genau, aber "Jetzt, als" klingt mir komisch. "Jetzt, da" ist gut.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Stimmt. Funktioniert (bezogen auf die Problematik hier) eigentlich nur mit Vergangenem (Damals, wo ich noch zur Schule ging/Damals, als ich noch zur Schule ging). Das Beispiel ist einfach schlecht gewählt von mir, sry :D

Comment: @Em1: Yep, mit "damals" klingt's prima.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Frage-Aussage-Ansatz führt m.E. in die Irre:

> Dort, **wo** ich herkomme, kann man „wo“ ohne Weiteres auch in einen Aussagesatz einbauen.

Der Duden kennt zwei „wo“:

- [**wo** als Konjunktion](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Konjunktion), synonym zu da / zumal:

  > warum hast du das gesagt, wo du doch weißt, wie empfindlich er ist (Duden-Originalbeispiel)

  Interessanterweise nennt noch das [Grimm'sche Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&lemid=GW24313&hitlist=&patternlist=&mode=Gliederung) diesen Gebrauch von „wo“ „umgangssprachlich“ (unter III.C.1).
- [**wo** als Adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Fragewort_Relativpronomen), eventuell synonym zu als / wenn: siehe mein erstes Beispiel (dort passt als/wenn aber nicht).

Beide „wo“ zusammengenommen decken also semantisch einen ziemlich weiten Bereich ab, was wohl das Risiko eines „nicht standardsprachlichen“ Gebrauchs erhöht.

Comment: _zaunpfahlausweich_ :-) Herzlichen Dank für den Hinweis! Was war nur los heute früh? Riskio und Konjuktion habe ich auch gleich richtiggestellt...

Comment: Verstehe, passt. Und der Duden-Link liefert auch gleich eine Ersetzung des "Wo" (auf die ich einfach nicht gekommen bin): *Jetzt, angesichts der Tatsache, dass ich in Bielefeld wohne* und weist auf einen weitere, zeitbezogene Bedeutung, nämlich *während*, hin.